# PHP POST checkbox issue

Tags: php, post, checkbox

I am getting some data using POST in PHP. When checkboxes are checked, there is no problem, but when if one of the rows have an unchecked checkbox, all order of checkboxes are gone. I tried to print array and I see that if a checkbox is unchecked, its value is not written.

For example if I have 5 rows and I check 2 of them. The size of this array is 2 instead of 5. How can I convert unchecked checkboxes into "0" value?

```
<input onchange="saveChanges();" type="checkbox" name="showS[]" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do several things.
One is to actually show what is checked by doing this:

```
<input onchange="saveChanges();" type="checkbox" name="showS[value1]" value="1">
```

You could also just use unique identifiers and not an array ofcourse. Another options is to do the difference with the value, not the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a value submitted in the POST request (use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to determine this) then set `false` where appropriate, otherwise use the value of the submitted field.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it with this logic

```
 <?php
      $checkbox = isset($_POST['checkbox'])?$_POST['checkbox']:0;
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is unchecked checkbox its not added to the _POST array so you dont get anything at all..

Answer (score 0):

Set an appropriate value for the checkbox (e.g. the value of the primary key column for the row in the database table to which the checkbox relates).

The deal with the *values* in the array, not the indexes.